# "Overlay" a shell prompt on top of a terminal session?

Tags: terminal, tmux, prompt

I have several CLI application ideas that would be nice to run as an "overlay" on top of my terminal session.

In other words I would like to superimpose a box containing a real live shell prompt on top of whatever is currently displaying in my terminal. Nothing more than that.

It could work exactly like `tmux` except instead of windows and panes, it would just be a one-line-high terminal on top of whatever is existing, but I don't really need a "real" one-line-high terminal; it could just be a prompt by some other means, if that's possible.

Any ideas of where to start solving this?

Comment: So you are looking more-or-less for a non-modifiable `tmux` layout without pane borders?

Comment: @peterph I'm not really sure what you mean. I'm just looking for any way of temporarily overlaying a shell prompt on top of my terminal so that if I'm in an ncurses app and I just want to run a quick command I can; like making a new tmux pane, typing a command, and closing the pane, but much faster and thus entirely different in terms of "user experience".

Comment: Do you mean a [scratchpad](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jasonwryan/5636783883/)?

Comment: Why not just create a new window? You would need some kind of hotkey to switch to your overlay anyway, so I don't see an advantage in that compared to a window.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich I think I see the advantage - just overwriting the topmost line of the console is **much** faster than splitting it in a terminal multiplexer (consider the resizing of the existing window) not even mentioning creating another X window. However on most todays hardware the difference will not be very noticeable.

Comment: @themirror another iteration: are you looking for a CLI/curses equivalent of [Tilda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilda_(software)), [Yakuake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakuake) or [Guake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guake)?

Comment: @peterph I'm not suggesting to use splitting. I'm suggesting that whenever one wants to quickly run a command, one just presses `CTRL+a c` (sorry, using `screen` hotkeys in my example here, I barely know `tmux`), runs the command, and then closes the window with `CTRL+d` again. In the long run, that'll be a much simpler solution than trying to figure out some workaround just to get another shell prompt in the current window :)

Comment: @MartinvonWittich ok, but still, there is the spawning of the shell. Hence a dedicated shortcut for switching to a predefined window would be faster.

Comment: It is faster in CPU time, but more importantly it is a very different UX; to be clear, all I want is a tmux pane that's one line high, floats *on top* of my current terminal, and disappears when I type and hit return.